# No resource identifier found for attribute 'twowayview_layoutManager' with TwoWayView 0.1.4

Tags: android, gradle, android-xml

I get this error when importing TwoWayView 0.1.4 with

```
     compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
```

This is the layout triggering the error

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:twowayview_layoutManager="ListLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How should I solve this?

PS: we need a TwoWayView tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app:twowayview_layoutManager="ListLayoutManager" will work only on

compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar' these new release.